# Need help in drawing the following Stacked Bar Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I want your help in drawing the following figure. I think it is called as stacked bar graph.
[image]

Comment: Search the `pgfplots` documentation for "ybar stacked".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This type of graph is easy to produce with the `pgfplots` package. See below for an example. For more details on `ybar stacked` graphs, see p77 of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf).

You should also consider transforming your `ybar stacked` graph into an `xbar stacked` graph (see p78 of the [pgfplots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)); those tend to be easier to parse.

**EDIT**: I have shamelessly adapted [Jake's very detailed answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36402/21891) to [Center nodes near coords in a stacked ybar plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36114/center-nodes-near-coords-in-a-stacked-ybar-plot) to add values in the bars:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread{
1   15  12  03  24  16  19
2   15  12  03  24  16  19
3   15  12  03  24  16  19
4   15  12  03  24  16  19
5   15  12  03  24  16  19
6   15  12  03  24  16  19  
}\datatable

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{%
            (\pgfplotspointmeta*10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)%
            /2*\pgfplots@y@veclength)%
        }
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    nodes near coords vertically centered/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            /pgfplots/calculate offset,
            yshift=-\testmacro
        },
        nodes near coords align=center
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,%
    bar width=15pt,%
    legend style={%
        at={(0,0)},%
        anchor=west,%
        at={(axis description cs:1.05,+0.5)}},%
    reverse legend,%
    xtick={1,2,...,6},%
    xticklabels={1,2,3,4,5,6},%
    enlarge x limits=0.1,%
    enlarge y limits=false,%
    ymin=0,%
    ymax=100.01,%
    ytick={0,10,...,100},%
    yticklabels={0\%,10\%,20\%,30\%,40\%,50\%,60\%,70\%,80\%,90\%,100\%},%
    xlabel={\textbf{Company}},%
    ylabel={\textbf{\% Distribution of efforts}},%
    point meta=explicit,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed zerofill,precision=1]{\pgfplotspointmeta}
    },
    every node near coord/.style={%
        check for zero/.code={ %
            \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfplotspointmeta}{0}{%
                \pgfkeys{/tikz/coordinate}%
            }{}%
        },%
        check for zero,%
        fill=white,%
        fill opacity=0.75,%
        text opacity=1,%
        font=\scriptsize,%
        inner ysep=0.5pt,%
    },%
    nodes near coords vertically centered,%
]
\addplot table [y=1, meta=1] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{A}
\addplot table [y=2, meta=2] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{B}
\addplot table [y=3, meta=3] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{C}
\addplot table [y=4, meta=4] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{D}
\addplot table [y=5, meta=5] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{E}
\addplot table [y=6, meta=6] \datatable;
\addlegendentry{F}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jubobs.. Is there a way to also write in the values in the bars as given in the picture?