# How to move percentage numbers in bar chart horizontally?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I want to to move the percentage numbers in horizontal direction so they don't overlap: [image: Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{testbar2/.style={
        xbar stacked,
        width=0.8\textwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        bar width=6mm, y=13mm,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%}, % <-- prints % sign after y coordinate value
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        nodes near coords align={center}, % <-- horizontal alignment centered of nodes 
        enlarge y limits=0.75, % <-- Adds vertical space so to not crop the bars
}}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[testbar2, legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.2cm}, every node near coord/.append style={yshift=0.5cm},
            ]
            \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (22.60,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (23.10,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (12.14,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (23.70,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (8.07,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (10.39,2)};
            \legend{A,B,A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},A\textsubscript{2},C}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you may consider to move percentage )(n smaller font) inside bars. In this case they meaning/belonging will be more clear (to my opinion).

Comment: I do understand you, but the problem with the last values remains unfortunately.

Comment: Moving the last 6.43% to the left (horizontally, and not vertically, btw) would lead to a reading issue, in my opinion, sonce it will stand over the wrong bar. You could consider writing your percentages diagonally, so they don't overlap and stay legible.

Comment: @sebGlav Haha my bad, confused horizontally and vertically. Could you show me, how it works? It would be a great help to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be an alternative.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotsset{,
    xmin=0,
    /tikz/font=\footnotesize,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=85pt,
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ytick = data, yticklabels = {1,2},
        xtick={0,20,...,100},
        tick align = outside, xtick pos = left,
        x post scale=1.3,   
        scale only axis,
        enlarge y limits=0.75, 
        xbar stacked,
        bar width=6mm, y=14mm,
        ytick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
        nodes near coords style={yshift=(-1)^\plotnum * 13pt},% shifts up or down nodes near coords <<<
        xticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},% <-- prints % sign after x tick value
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ]
        \addplot coordinates{(20.00,1) (22.60,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (23.10,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(11.43,1) (12.14,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(28.57,1) (23.70,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(6.43,1) (8.07,2)};
            \addplot coordinates{(5.00,1) (10.39,2)};
            \legend{A,B,A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},A\textsubscript{2},C}         
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

`yshift`  taken from [shifts up or down nodes near coords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349619/161015)

Comment: This is a really nice answer. Is there a way to make just the percentage number in footnote size and the legend etc. in normal size? And where in the code do find the option to move the percentage numbers up an down?

Comment: @Friedrich Falkner Try  adding `font=\normalsize` to the legend style. Up and down is done by `yshift`, See the link after the code.

Comment: +1 for the `yshift=(-1)^\plotnum` workaround. Very nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I would rotate picture and write labels on bars sides:

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=66mm,
    ybar stacked,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    xtick = {1,2},
    xmin=0.5, xmax=3,
    ymin=0, ymax=100,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\%},
%
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%},
    nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize, anchor=west, xshift=1ex},
%
legend style = {at={(0.5,-0.12)},
                anchor=north, font=\small,
                legend columns=-1},
    ]
\addplot coordinates{(1, 20.00) (2, 22.60)};
\addplot coordinates{(1, 28.57) (2, 23.10)};
\addplot coordinates{(1, 11.43) (2, 12.14)};
\addplot coordinates{(1, 28.57) (2, 23.70)};
\addplot coordinates{(1,  6.43) (2,  8.07)};
\addplot coordinates{(1,  5.00) (2, 10.39)};

\legend{A,B,
        A\textsubscript{1},B\textsubscript{1},
        A\textsubscript{2},C}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```