# Space node values evenly

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to space out the node values on the bars so that they are clearly visible. What do you recommend for the ones that are partially hidden? Can I do this automagically? Also I'd like to use the plot coordinates rather than the cumulative values of probability. Where abouts is that in the pgfplots handbook?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
   %\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
%\tikzexternalize
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,
backgrounds,fit,positioning,shapes.symbols,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar stacked,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.50)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={Probability},
symbolic x coords={{Direct Care}, Housekeeping, Mealtimes, {Medication Round},
Miscellaneous,{Personal Care}},
xtick=data,
ymax=1,
x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
every node near coord/.style={
      check for zero/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotspointmeta-.1}
        \pgfmathfloatifflags{\pgfmathresult}{-}{
           \pgfkeys{/tikz/coordinate}
        }{}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
      }, check for zero, yshift=-5pt, font=\footnotesize},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords align={center}
]
\addplot+[ybar,bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.258883249)
({Housekeeping},0.176470588)
({Mealtimes},0.19047619)
({Medication Round},0.207207207)
({Miscellaneous},0.222222222)
({Personal Care},0.615384615)
};
\addplot+[ybar,bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.015228426)
({Housekeeping},0.235294118)
({Mealtimes},0)
({Medication Round},0.027027027)
({Miscellaneous},0)
({Personal Care},0.153846154)
};
\addplot+[ybar,bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.152284264)
({Housekeeping},0.058823529)
({Mealtimes},0.333333333)
({Medication Round},0.351351351)
({Miscellaneous},0.180555556)
({Personal Care},0.153846154)
};
\legend{{Handwash only},{Gloves only},{Alcohol rub only}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use the plot coordinates with `point meta=rawy` as described (very sparsely) in section _4.22. SKIPPING OR CHANGING COORDINATES / FILTERS_

Comment: [In this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36114/center-nodes-near-coords-in-a-stacked-ybar-plot) Jake gives a solution for placing the labels in the middle of a bar segment. However, it only seems to work with `\addplot table`, so you'd probably need to change your data input.

Comment: Use explicit `width` and `height` such that there is enough space for the numbers to fit in (with smaller fonts maybe). Otherwise my opinion is that it looks very crowded.

Comment: @TomBombadil Jake's answers, gives this snippet of code: `calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(\pgfplotspointmeta*10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@y)/2*\pgfplots@y@veclength)}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
    }` How can I get rid of the bit that creates 10^ and just place the values in the middle?

Comment: I do not think it will ever look tidy if you place 3 bars per each of the 6 categories behind/on top of each other. Maybe you should think of another way to present the data. I'm sure there is one.
I do not quite understand the meaning of your figures, do the probabilities add up to one on some dimension?

Comment: I'm happy if I can just put the values in my `\addplot+[...`as the text centered in the bars. Can this be done¿

Answer (score 1):

- Starting with version 1.9 of *pgfplots* the labels are placed automatically in the middle of the bars
- The plot coordinates can be used with `point meta=rawy`
- I would recommend not printing the labels of very small values. This can be done e.g. like this:

---

```
nodes near coords=%
    {   \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\bigenough}{\pgfplotspointmeta > 0.05 ? 1 : 0}%
        \ifthenelse{\bigenough = 1}%
            {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}%
            {}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    },
```

This turns on the *floating point unit* library and sets the number format to fixed as otherwise `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` can't use it. Then a check is performed weather or not the value is bigger than some arbitrarily chosen limit, here `0.05`. If it is bigger, draw it, otherwise don't. Then disable the *fpu* library.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   ybar stacked,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.50)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Probability},
    symbolic x coords={{Direct Care}, Housekeeping, Mealtimes, {Medication Round}, Miscellaneous,{Personal Care}},
    xtick=data,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    point meta=rawy,
    height=8cm,
    width=10cm,
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    every node near coord/.style={font=\fontsize{6}{7}\selectfont},
    nodes near coords=%
    {   \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\bigenough}{\pgfplotspointmeta > 0.05 ? 1 : 0}%
        \ifthenelse{\bigenough = 1}%
            {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}}%
            {}
        %\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
    },
]
\addplot+[bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.258883249)
({Housekeeping},0.176470588)
({Mealtimes},0.19047619)
({Medication Round},0.207207207)
({Miscellaneous},0.222222222)
({Personal Care},0.615384615)
};
\addplot+[bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.015228426)
({Housekeeping},0.235294118)
({Mealtimes},0)
({Medication Round},0.027027027)
({Miscellaneous},0)
({Personal Care},0.153846154)
};
\addplot+[bar width=20pt] plot coordinates {({Direct Care},0.152284264)
({Housekeeping},0.058823529)
({Mealtimes},0.333333333)
({Medication Round},0.351351351)
({Miscellaneous},0.180555556)
({Personal Care},0.153846154)
};
\legend{{Handwash only},{Gloves only},{Alcohol rub only}}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]