# Place values from table centred within bars in a stacked bar chart

Tags: tables, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

I would like to get the values from the the columns Cd, Cr, and Ni showing on their respective sections of the bars in the chart. I would like them to be aligned in the center of each section. 
I have used `nodes near coords` and `\addplot` with coordinates to show the values. The first three fit within the correct place but they are not centered. Furthermore, the subsequent `\addplot` show up in the wrong position.
Could I get some help with this issue?
Thank you in advance for the help.
[image: example of where my chart is at]

Code is

```
\documentclass[border={0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,
 every axis/.style={axis on top},
 tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\small\itshape,xshift={-15}},
 every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
 legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
 label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}, 
 }
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Species                         Cd      Cr      Ni
V.\space c.\space cochiensis    3.67    2.16    2.27
L.\space teres                  2.76    0       0
L.\space s.\space claibornensis 2.52    0       1.94
A.\space pectorosa              2.34    0       1.34
L.\space subviridis             2.34    0       0
U.\space imbecillis             2.26    0.76    1.44
V.\space vibex                  2.21    0       1.58
C.\space fluminalis             1.39    0       0
P.\space casertanum             1.17    0       0
P.\space compressum             1.08    0       0
C.\space rhizophorae            0.40    0       0
P.\space favidens               0.24    0       0
L.\space marginalis             0.10    0       0
M.\space nervosa                0       1.08    1.82
R.\space cuneata                0       0.90    0
A.\space plicata                0       0.85    1.69
L.\space siliquoidea            0       0.80    1.42
M.\space falcata                0       0.42    1.63
H.\space perovalis              0       0       1.56
V.\space nebulosa               0       0       1.35
H.\space cumingii               0       -0.81   0
D.\space chilensis              0       -1.09   0
}\testdata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
            xbar stacked,
            xmin=-3,
            xmax=8,         
            xticklabel style=transparent,    
            xtick style=transparent,
            ytick style=transparent,            
            axis y line*=middle,
            every inner y axis line/.append style = {dotted, ultra thick},
            height=11cm,
            width=11.9cm,           
            enlarge y limits={abs=0.725},
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.725},            
            xlabel={RS = $\log (LC_{50\textit{Lf}}/LC_{50\textit{i}})$},             
            ytick=\empty,
            legend style={at={(0.8,0.6)},anchor=north west, draw=none},            
            nodes near coords,
            visualization depends on=x\as\myx,          
            nodes near coords align={center},
            every node near coord/.append style={anchor ={180-sign(\myx)*180},font=\footnotesize},
            point meta = explicit symbolic         
]
\addlegendimage{empty legend},
\addplot [fill=black!90!black!45] table [x=Cr, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};   % "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=black!90!black!20] table [x=Cd, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
\addplot [fill=black!5] table [x=Ni, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
\addplot [only marks,mark size=0pt,point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,nodes near coords style={anchor=east,font =\small\itshape}] 
    table[x expr={-1*ifthenelse(\thisrow{Cd}+\thisrow{Cr}+\thisrow{Ni}>0,
        \thisrow{Cd}+\thisrow{Cr}+\thisrow{Ni},0)},y expr=\coordindex,meta=Species]  {\testdata};
\addplot[black] coordinates{(2.16,0)[2.16]};%shows up well but not 'center'.
\addplot[black] coordinates{(3.67,0)[3.67]};%shows up well but not 'center'.
\addplot[black] coordinates{(2.27,0)[2.27]};%shows up well but not 'center'.
%
%all other \addplot entries from table.
%
\addplot[black] coordinates{(0,20)};
\addplot[black] coordinates{(-0.81,20)[-0.81]};%shows up on the wrong position. 
\addplot[black] coordinates{(0,20)};
\addplot[black] coordinates{(0,21)};
\addplot[black] coordinates{(-1.09,21)[-1.09]};%shows up on the wrong position.
\addplot[black] coordinates{(0,21)};


\addlegendentry{\hspace{-0.85cm}\textbf\small{Metals}},
\addlegendentry{Cr(VI)},
\addlegendentry{Cd(II)},
\addlegendentry{Ni(II)},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the two points you raise I think one of them can be addressed rather easily. The issue is that these are *stacked* plots. However, it seems that you only want to show the `x` values. Then you seem to want to suppress the nodes if the bar is too small. This can be achieved with a style

```
\pgfplotsset{my meta/.style={point meta=\thisrow{#1},
every node near coord/.append style={%
 opacity={ifthenelse(abs(\csname my#1\endcsname)><threshold>,1,0)}}}}
```

where `<threshold>` is taken to be 0.5 in the below example. For the horizontal centering I use a variant of [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36402).

```
\documentclass[border={0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,
 every axis/.style={axis on top},
 tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily\small\itshape,xshift={-15}},
 every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
 legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
 label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}, 
 }
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    calculate offset/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}    
        \pgfmathsetmacro\testmacro{(10^\pgfplots@data@scale@trafo@EXPONENT@x)*%
         \csname my#1\endcsname/2*\pgfplots@x@veclength)}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    nodes near coords horizontally centered/.style={
        every node near coord/.append style={
            /pgfplots/calculate offset=#1,
            xshift=-\testmacro
        },
    }
}
\makeatother 

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
Species                         Cd      Cr      Ni
V.\space c.\space cochiensis    3.67    2.16    2.27
L.\space teres                  2.76    0       0
L.\space s.\space claibornensis 2.52    0       1.94
A.\space pectorosa              2.34    0       1.34
L.\space subviridis             2.34    0       0
U.\space imbecillis             2.26    0.76    1.44
V.\space vibex                  2.21    0       1.58
C.\space fluminalis             1.39    0       0
P.\space casertanum             1.17    0       0
P.\space compressum             1.08    0       0
C.\space rhizophorae            0.40    0       0
P.\space favidens               0.24    0       0
L.\space marginalis             0.10    0       0
M.\space nervosa                0       1.08    1.82
R.\space cuneata                0       0.90    0
A.\space plicata                0       0.85    1.69
L.\space siliquoidea            0       0.80    1.42
M.\space falcata                0       0.42    1.63
H.\space perovalis              0       0       1.56
V.\space nebulosa               0       0       1.35
H.\space cumingii               0       -0.81   0
D.\space chilensis              0       -1.09   0
}\testdata

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{my meta/.style={point meta=\thisrow{#1},
nodes near coords horizontally centered=#1,
every node near coord/.append style={%
opacity={ifthenelse(abs(\csname my#1\endcsname)>0.5,1,0)}}}}
\begin{axis}[
            xbar stacked,
            xmin=-3,
            xmax=8,         
            xticklabel style=transparent,    
            xtick style=transparent,
            ytick style=transparent,            
            axis y line*=middle,
            every inner y axis line/.append style = {dotted, ultra thick},
            height=11cm,
            width=11.9cm,           
            enlarge y limits={abs=0.725},
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.725},            
            xlabel={RS = $\log (LC_{50\textit{Lf}}/LC_{50\textit{i}})$},             
            ytick=\empty,
            legend style={at={(0.8,0.6)},anchor=north west, draw=none},            
            nodes near coords,
            visualization depends on=x\as\myx, 
            visualization depends on=\thisrow{Cr}\as\myCr,
            visualization depends on=\thisrow{Cd}\as\myCd,
            visualization depends on=\thisrow{Ni}\as\myNi,         
            nodes near coords align={center},
            every node near coord/.append style={%anchor={180-sign(\myx)*180},
            font=\tiny},
]
\addlegendimage{empty legend},
\addplot [fill=black!90!black!45,my meta=Cr] table [x=Cr, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};   % "First" column against the data index
\addplot [fill=black!90!black!20,my meta=Cd] table [x=Cd, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
\addplot [fill=black!5,my meta=Ni] table [x=Ni, y expr=\coordindex] {\testdata};
\addplot [only marks,mark size=0pt,point meta=explicit symbolic,
    nodes near coords,nodes near coords style={anchor=east,font=\small\itshape,opacity=1}] 
    table[x expr={-1*ifthenelse(\thisrow{Cd}+\thisrow{Cr}+\thisrow{Ni}>0,
        \thisrow{Cd}+\thisrow{Cr}+\thisrow{Ni},0)},y expr=\coordindex,meta=Species]  {\testdata};
\addlegendentry{\hspace{-0.85cm}\textbf\small{Metals}},
\addlegendentry{Cr(VI)},
\addlegendentry{Cd(II)},
\addlegendentry{Ni(II)},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is amazing, thank you so much! Would reducing the font size allow me to display a few more values at least? I would like the values for Cr(VI) to show...

Comment: @Emmo03 I think so, yes. You can try to set `font=\tiny` or use `scale`.The threshold is set with `opacity={ifthenelse(\csname my#1\endcsname>1,1,0)}`, so if you use `opacity={ifthenelse(\csname my#1\endcsname>0.5,1,0)}`, values larger than 0.5 will be shown.

Comment: Great! I will try with that to see how many more values I can get to show. Thank you so much again!

Comment: @Emmo03 There was an error which I fixed now.

Comment: thanks! I noticed that the alignment shifted. Now it looks really neat.  I am also trying to get the negative values showing, but  then I get all the zeros too! can I establish some sort of threshold > 0 < so zero is out?

Comment: @Emmo03 That's easy: take the absolute value: `opacity={ifthenelse(abs(\csname my#1\endcsname)>0.5,1,0)}`. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: oh I see! cool. That is a lot of certainty for a cat in such a quantum superposition! I learn a lot thanks to your help. I have even been able to help someone creating a chart the other day.

Comment: Just had a thought for those values that do not fit in their bars. Would it be possible to place them outside the bars? can I set up `nodes near coords` for that when there is `every node near coord/append style` already defined?

Comment: @Emmo03 You can place them outside but this makes the plot very busy, doesn't it? Some of the thin bars are surrounded by other things in all directions.

Comment: yeah it is true. I am quite restricted with the number of pages though. I need to condense all that info in one chart. I also thought of referencing them (a,b,c,..) and provide the values as a footnote?

Comment: @Emmo03 I do not know. The graph is to give the reader a feeling for the values. If you want to show all values precisely, you can use a table.

Comment: I actually have the table, but was hoping to get all the info in the chart. I think you are right, and it is too much. I will probably use the chart to convey the visual comparison among metals and use the table for the actual values. Thanks for the advice!